# Data in Rows Instead of Columns

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

The default List layout uses column headers with columns of data beneath them. This will not work for my report. I need to create an employee profile report that will return about 75 fields (job title, location, tax status, payroll deductions, etc.). This is a report that I want to be able to print on a single page for each employee. Using the The default List layout extends the data out in columns beyond the limits of a printed page, even in landscape.

How can I get my report to display in rows instead of columns, so that the field headers go from the top of the page to the bottom, with the data to the right of the headers. Even this will not be long enough to fit on a single page (that is easily readable), so I will need a second list to the right of the first. Like this:

```
    Name:       data                     Company:             data
    Location:   data                     Employee Number:     data
    Job Title:  data                     Date Hired:          data
```

Thanks!

Comment: Going from memory, but here goes.  On the properties of the page, set the query to be whatever query all your columns are from.  Then add a table to the page with your desired layout. Then I think you can just drag fields from the query and drop them in the desired cells.  For the field headers, you may have to use a text box.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Repeater Table object to do what you want. This should be available in your toolbox. You group on the value you want to repeat on, likely an employee identifier in your case, and section on that value. That will produce one table per unique identifier value. In the table itself you can configure the number of rows and columns to fit the layout you want to produce and you are free to drag and drop objects from the model or query into the cells as needed.